# async argument in useQueries (getting undefined) – React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm using a hook to fetch a user from firebase:

```
  const [user, isUserLoading, isUserError] = useDocument(
    doc(getFirestore(app), 'users', currentUserId)
  );
```

I'm interested in an array in the `user` object:

```
const currentUserSurveys = user && user?.data().surveys;
```

Now I want to pass `currentUserSurveys` which is an array of strings as an argument to this hook:

```
const clientSurveys = useClientSurveys(currentUserSurveys);
```

The hook is defined like this:

```
function useClientSurveys(surveysIds) {
  const { isAdmin } = useAdminStatus();

  const clientSurveysQueries = useQueries({
    queries: surveysIds?.map(surveyId => {
      return {
        queryKey: ['clientSurvey', surveyId],
        queryFn: () => getSurvey(surveyId),
        enabled: !!surveysIds && surveysIds.length > 0 && !isAdmin,
      };
    }),
  });
  return clientSurveysQueries;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

I thought this line helps to only call the query when `surveysIds` is defined:

```
enabled: !!surveysIds && surveysIds.length > 0 && !isAdmin,
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

```
(surveysIds || [])?.map(surveyId =>
```